# Probability of creating a single loop

Tags: probability, combinatorics, factorial

I have n pieces of rope in a bowl. I pick two ends randomly and tie them together, and continue picking two more ends and tying them together until there are no free ends. What is the probability that I end up with one large loop?

It seems to me that this probability is the product of 
$\dfrac{(2n-j)}{(2n-j+1)}$
for j$=2,4,6,...$etc... so that, for example, if $n=5$, we have, after picking one end from the 10, it is:

$$\frac{8}{9} \times \frac{6}{7} \times \frac{4}{5} \times \frac{2}{3},$$

but I am having trouble finding a closed-form expression for this sum. Any help would be  much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{2k+1}
 = \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)}{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k+1)}
 = \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)^2}{\prod_{k=1}^n 2k(2k+1)}
 = \frac{4^n (n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}
$$

Comment: thanks. how did you get the last expression from the second-to-last?

Comment: @GrunvaldskayaBitva the denominator is straight forward, write it out. The numerator -- note that $(2k)^2 = 4k^2$ so $$\prod_{k=1}^n 4k^2 = 4^n \prod_{k=1}^n k \prod_{k=1}^n k = 4^n \cdot n! \cdot n!$$